# Converting AppleMaps Coordinates to Google Place IDs

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit

I'm afraid this is a general question, no code as such just yet.

I've built my app to date with Apple MapKit, and it is generating locations (strings & coordinates). I don't want to rebuild this with Google Maps SDK for iOS.

I'm looking to use Firebase as the back-end and they have some useful analytics when passing in Google Place IDs.

**My question is therefore whether you can convert coordinates into Google Place IDs and therefore what my best option would be to achieve this?**

It would obviously best if this did not involve using the SDK and I could somehow use an online API to convert the coordinates to place IDs...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you have address of coordinate then use in below api and you able to get the PlaceID

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

check more detail in below link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#geocoding